"He does nothing but ...": "talk" or "talking"?

He does nothing but _.
A. talk
B. talking

Which one is correct? I chose talking, because it is the object of "does". I have heard "you do all the talking". Others chose talk, and said that does is only an auxiliary verb.

He talks, he does talk, you know. He does nothing but talk.

The others are right.
Technically, "He does talk" is a grammatical sentence, even though it's archaic or stilted. You see things like this sometimes in old student readers, or in archaic usages ("Hark, hark, the dog doth bark!"). These days it would be more common to just use simple present, "He talks."
We call the "do" back into service when we need to do more with the verb. For one thing, if we want to negate it, we say "He does not talk" (or the contraction "doesn't"). Similarly, we need it for the idiomatic usage "does nothing but [verb]."* Most tellingly, if we revert the sentence back to a simple single verb, we wouldn't say "He does talking." It's not just stilted or archaic, it was never idiomatic. It might be imaginable for certain times that an "-ing" word is recognized as a specific activity or hobby ("I do chess" "I do swimming")... but only maybe; usually a different verb other than "do" would be used there.

* Kind of a red herring, but "He does talk" would not be archaic if used for emphasis: "He doesn't talk." "He does talk. You just don't listen." (Or in the childish retort, "Does not!" "Does too!", the verb has been done away with entirely and all that survives omission is "does," along with an extra word to negate or to assert.)

He does nothing but [verb]. is stilted? I disagree with that. There is no flipping possible. He talks. He does talk a lot. talking is another structure entirely. He does talk. might be used on conversation. There are tons and tons of pragmatic things in English that are not about grammar per se.

@Lambie Sorry, I should clarify that sentence. The antecedent of "it" is the "He does talk" that follows.

It can also be used in concurring with another’s remark as in John groaned, “George? Not that chatterbox,” and Joan shrugged, “He does talk.”

When I saw it's archaic or stilted, I thought "Yeah, I agree" - then I realized you were talking about He does talk. Which I agree is a "weird" utterance today (probably always was! :). Anyway, I was gratified to find NGrams confirming my opinion that You do nothing but talk is "antiquated", having been replaced by All you do is talk.

@FumbleFingers "You want to do naught but ride about, Sally..." "I do nothing but win, win, win..." "I want nothing but to have some fun / I've a suspicion I'm not the only one..."
